# Get groups by ID

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

For retrieve a specific group by id , I use this request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=id eq 'xxxxx'
```

Now I am interested in getting many groups, but it looks like the filter does not support multiple elements. When I tried this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=id eq 'xxxxx' or id eq 'yyyy'
```

It returns this error:

> Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'id' of resource 'Group'.

Someone can confirm me this?

Comment: If you already know the group id, why don't you directly use /groups/{groupId} to fetch group details? What is your use case scenario?

Comment: Because I want to create a subscription for webhook for many groups and I'm not interested to make a subscription for each group.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states the expression `groups?$filter=id eq '--group-id-1--' or id eq '--group-id-1--'` is not supported but the good news you could utilize [`/directoryObjects/getByIds` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getbyids?view=graph-rest-beta) instead to retrieve *the list of groups by their ids*

> Note: the method is available in both `v1` and `beta` versions

**Example**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/getByIds
Content-type: application/json

{
    "ids":["--group-id-1--","--group-id-2--"],
    "types":["group"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. I can reproduce your issue on my side, not sure why but it should be designed to be like this.

The format of the query is complete right, if we filter by another property except the `id`, like `displayName`, it works fine.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq 'xxxx' or displayName eq 'xxxx'
```

[image]